# Calling an image alt text with Ruby Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

Ok, I'm trying to access an image stored in an image library which on click closes the image library pop up and inserts the image into the page.

The html for the image is;

```
<img src="/uploads/images/thumbs/10.png?504" alt="Find Us" width="140" onclick="$('#removeButton', window.opener.document).show();
                                $('#myImgId', window.opener.document).show();
                                $('#imageHeadingID', window.opener.document).val('13');
                                $('#myImgId', window.opener.document).attr('src', '/uploads/images/thumbs/10.png');
                                window.close()">
```

As a note, the ?504 is not static and changes each time the image library is open so I cant use it as an id value.

I've tried the following lines of code in turn, all without success (gleaned from google and stack overflow).

```
find("img[@alt='Find Us']").click
$browser.cell(:text => "Find Us").click
$browser.image(:src => /10/).click
$browser.image(:src => "/10.png").click
$browser.link(:text => "Find Us").click
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how those lines of code do work? I would expect `$browser.image(:src => /10/).click` to work. What is the error that occurs when doing it?

Comment: Given that you are getting an unable to locate element error, there could be a number of different issues. Without seeing the entire page, it is difficult to debug. However I had written a [list of some common problems](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/).

Answer (score 0):

Try identify by `:alt` :

```
$browser.image(:alt => "Find Us").click
```

But, it's strange, cause, `$browser.image(:src => /10/).click` - must work also.

Comment: Hi Justin, the error I'm getting (having also tried your suggestion) is; unable to locate element, using (:alt => "Find Us", :tag_name=>"img")

Comment: @Cantorion it's strange, are this image inside the iframe?

Comment: it doesnt appear to be an i frame, all images are contained within cells inside; <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

Comment: @Cantorion can you add html of this table or url of this page?

Comment: Alex, the html is;[<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:20%">
<div style="margin-bottom:10px; min-height:60px;">Find Us</div>
<div style="width:100%">
<img src="/uploads/images/thumbs/10.png?8890" alt="Find Us" width="140" onclick="$('#removeButton', window.opener.document).show();
       $('#myImgId', window.opener.document).show();
                         $('#imageHeadingID', window.opener.document).val('13');
                       $('#myImgId', window.opener.document).attr('src', '/uploads/images/thumbs/10.png');
                                    window.close()">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex and Justin that using `src` should work, but

Have you tried using an XPath?

Something like `browser.img(:xpath => "/html/.../img").click`

You can get the XPath to the image pretty easily with Chrome by right-clicking the image-->Inspect Element-->then right-click on the relevant line of HTML in the developer tools that have opened. If the image is always in the same place on the page (regardless of any change in the `src`), this method should work.